# The example of weak convergence but not strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

I am reading the following book:

`Optimization by Vector Space Methods` written by `D. G. Luenberger`

My problem comes from the Example 1. in p.127

> In $X = l_2$, consider the elements $x_n=\{0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots\}$ with $1$ in the $n$-th place. For any $y=\{\eta_1,\eta_2,\ldots\}\in l_2=X^*$, we have $(x_n\mid y)=\eta_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Thus $x_n\rightarrow 0$ weakly. However $x_n$ does not converge to $0$ strongly since $\|x_n\|=1$.

I am confused about why $\eta_n \rightarrow 0$?  If I pick $\eta_i = 0$ for all $i\neq n$ and $\eta_n=1$?

Kindly put some similar questions:

1. [equivalency of weak and strong convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387242/equivalency-of-weak-and-strong-convergence)
2. [Weakly convergence but not strongly - properties of limsup and liminf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591983/weakly-convergence-but-not-strongly-properties-of-limsup-and-liminf)
3. [What is a sequence of functions that converge weakly in Lp, but not strongly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829083/what-is-a-sequence-of-functions-that-converge-weakly-in-lp-but-not-strongly)

Comment: y is fixed, it does not change with $x_n$. So your example would really be $y=(1,1,...)$ which is not in $l^2$. It might help to properly distinguish between indices, since $x_n$ is a sequence of sequences.

Comment: @Ian I am still confused why $y$ is fixed. To say $\{x_n\}$ converges weakly to 0 if for any $y$ such that $\langle x_n,y\rangle \rightarrow \langle 0,y\rangle$. So we have to test it for every $y$. This is the point I am still confused.

Comment: Yes but you freeze y and then have a sequence of scalars. Thus $y_i \to 0$, and since $(x_n,y)=y_n$ you get the result.

Comment: @Ian I see thanks!

Comment: What's $X^*$? Is it some dual?

Comment: @mavavilj yes! dual space of $X$

Comment: @sleevechen What is it?

Comment: @mavavilj you can read that book p.106. The short answer is the space of all bounded linear functionals on $X$.